# Random 'Connection Refused' Errors when making get requests to my kubernetes cluster

Tags: http, nginx, kubernetes, networking, routes

Pretty standard setup

Nginx Ingress, with an external IP
When sending bulk requests (serially) to the IP about half of them end up erroring out...example here:

```
$ curl -vI http://my-ip
*   Trying my-ip:80...
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:02 --:--:--     0* connect to my-ip port 80 failed: Connection refused
* Failed to connect to my-ip port 80: Connection refused
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:02 --:--:--     0
* Closing connection 0
curl: (7) Failed to connect to my-ip port 80: Connection refused
```

The other half promptly return 200 status codes.

The requests with 200 status codes I can see in the nginx controller pod logs, however I don't see anything for the Connection refused requests

The nginx pod is healthy throughout the requests, with no crashes or abnormal behavior. I am calling the nginx external IP directly

```
nginx          ingress-nginx-1636864778-controller                  LoadBalancer   10.101.134.218   my-ip   80:30892/TCP,443:32566/TCP     74d
```

Not sure where to continue from here, if theses requests aren't even reaching the controller pod?

Answer (score 1):

[image]

The image above shows how HTTP requests are delivered to the pod through a LoadBalancer svc. So the problem may be related to your specific node or port availibility.